# How to create react bootstrap table with no isKey column/unique column?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table and it is expecting isKey for unique column.I don't have unique column.So I want to set rowid as unique column.when I give non unique column as key if I do expand row all rows with same values get expanded.So I want to set rowid as unique column.Please suggest how to set rowid/index as unique key.

[referred this link but no luck](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/688)